# Passing Data from Fragment's RecycleView to Activity

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to pass data from one my `HomeFragment's RecyclerView` to my `CategoryServiceActivity`. I'm trying to pass my selected index of the `RecyclerView` so that way I can set the correct category name as the title on my `supportActionBar` instead of having "Category" as my title. Do I need to pass the selected name when I set the `setOnClickListener` on my `PopularCategoriesAdapter`, or should I be passing it into my `CategoryServiceActivity`? Thank you.

**My "Category" Title Issue**

[image]

[image]

**My "Category" End Result**

[image]

**CategoryServiceActivity.kt**

```
class CategoryServiceActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var selectedCategory: Category
    val jobServices = ArrayList<JobService>()
    val jobServicesDatabaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child(REF_JOB_SERVICES)

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_category_service)

        val toolbar = findViewById<Toolbar>(R.id.toolbar)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

        supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
        supportActionBar?.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true)
        supportActionBar?.setTitle("Category")
    }

}
```

**Category.kt**

```
data class Category constructor(val category: String, val categoryImage: String)
```

**HomeFragment.kt**

```
lateinit var popularCategoriesAdapter: PopularCategoriesAdapter
val categories = ArrayList<Category>()

popularCategoriesAdapter = PopularCategoriesAdapter(categories)

    val popularCategoriesRecyclerView = view.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.popularCategoriesRecyclerView)
    popularCategoriesRecyclerView.apply {
        layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false)
        adapter = popularCategoriesAdapter
        setHasFixedSize(true)
    }

    categoriesDatabaseRef.orderByChild("category").addValueEventListener(object: ValueEventListener {
    @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
    override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        categories.clear()
        for (snap in snapshot.children) {
            val category = Category(snap.child("category").getValue(String::class.java)!! ,
                snap.child("categoryImage").getValue(String::class.java)!!)
            categories.add(category)
        }
        popularCategoriesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
   }

   override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
        Log.d("HomeFragment", "LoadPost:onCancelled", error.toException())
   }
})
```

**PopularCategoriesAdapter.kt**

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder?.bindCategory(category[position])

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener { v ->
            val context: Context = v.context
            val intent = Intent(context, CategoryServiceActivity::class.java)
            context.startActivity(intent)
        }
}
```

Comment: I think this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WueAM7LR9X0&ab_channel=AlexMamo) and this [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FireApp/tree/master/app/src/main/java/ro/alexmamo/firebase/main/profile/movies) might help.

Answer (score 0):

you can add bundle.putString() for fragment or intent.putString() for activity. for your case maybe you can like this.

in your fragment

```
val intent = Intent(context, CategoryServiceActivity::class.java)
intent.putString("key", value)
context.startActivity(intent)
```

in your activity

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_category_service)

    val toolbar = findViewById<Toolbar>(R.id.toolbar)
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

    supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
    supportActionBar?.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true)
    supportActionBar?.setTitle("Category")
    
    val value = intent.getStringExtra("key")
}
```

hope can solve your problem

Comment: Can I get clarification please? Where do I get the "key" and "value" from?

Comment: for the "key" its just key to identify your passing data, for the name is up to you and make sure the key is identify what the data passing. for example you want passing name so the key you can use intent.putString("name", "Zachary Smouse"). for the value its mean what the data do you want to passing

Comment: Could I pass the `itemView[position]` since I need to pass the selected category?